# Flush data to file frequently for long running command?

Tags: pipe

I have a command that processes data slowly. The command processes lines from a file and writes the results to the output file `data.txt`:

`my_command > data.txt`

The issue I have is that I'd like to examine output lines in the `data.txt` file as they are processed. The problem is that no output appears in my output file until the OS decides to dump data to the output file, which happens every few hours. Is there anyway I can force data to be flushed to the file more frequently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to unbuffer your command's stdout using [stdbuf](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) from GNU Coreutils.
I doubt I would be able to explain the technicalities behind it any better than the author does [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)